# Exercises for group actions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, permutations

I am reading Dummit and Foote and I feel like I am weak with group actions. I would very much like to have more practice regarding them, but none of the books I have seen go into group actions as much as D&F, and I haven't seen enough exercises in D&F of the type I am looking for. I would like to do more problems of the sort:

1) Prove that if $Q_8$ acts faithfully on a set $S$, then $|S| \ge 8$.

2) If $G$ is a group of order $12$ which has four 3-Sylows, then $G \cong A_4$.

3) Let $G$ be a $p$ - group which acts on a set $S$, and let $S^G$ be the set of fixed elements of the action. Then $|S| \equiv |S^G| \pmod p$

Is there any source of these, or could you please tell me more of these problems? Thank you so much!

Comment: All three questions have been answered here. For example, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089825/a-group-of-order-12-either-has-a-normal-3-sylow-subgroup-or-is-isomorphic-t) for the second question. So the source is this site here (or a book on group theory). Can you find the other two questions? (Hint for 1. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517434/show-that-q-8-is-not-isomorphic-to-a-subgroup-of-s-4-conclude-that-q-8-i)).

Comment: Google for "group actions" and "exercises" to find more!

Comment: Usually Sylow theorems are proved using group actions, so looking at that section might yield some exercises.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks, I will look around!

Comment: You can start from MSE itself by tagging "group-actions"